# How to format dates in format yyddd having no leading zeros

Tags: c#, database, datetime, ibm-midrange

I am dealing with dates coming from the AS/400 that are a form of julian date. January 1st 2000 comes back as a string value of "1". If the date were in true julian form it would look like 2000001.  The date 12/31/2049 is comes back from the AS/400 as "49365". Is there a way to format these dates in my C# code to look like standard short dates?

Comment: It's not clear what relation this really has to Julian dates... why would January 1st 2000 be 2000001?

Comment: Looks to me like `yyddd` or `ccyyddd`: `cc` = two-digit century, `yy` = two-digit year and `ddd` = day of year.

Comment: Is this _stored in the database_ as a `date` datatype (but with a `*JUL datfmt`)?  If so, is it possible to convert it to *ISO (either permanently in the database, or on demand with `CAST()` in SQL)?  That may be your best bet...

Comment: Okay, this doesn't appear to be likely, as internally it seems to be converting it to the 'default' date format anyways.  So, I'm assuming it's actually stored as a string, not as a date datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does January 1, 2001 look like?

If it looks like "1001", you can pad on the left with zeros to 5 digits and then extract the 2-digit year as the first two digits and the day-of-year number as the last 3. It should then be a simple matter to convert the day-of-year number to a month and day; if nothing else you can do it with a bunch of `if` statements on day ranges.

If it looks like "11" because there are no leading zeros in the day number, you're just out of luck as there is no way to differentiate between many dates, such as January 1, 2001 and January 11, 2000.

P.S. These aren't [Julian dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_date), they're a variation on [ordinal dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date).

Comment: January 1, 2001 would look like 11 in this system.

Comment: @dtinsley: You're out of luck then, because there is no way to tell if "11" means "January 1, 2001" or "January 11, 2000". And the same for many other strings of less than 5 digits.

Comment: Yep, if that is the case, something is missing. If you have access to the code from the system, I would see how they are building the dates. If you don't I would look for a century field or something. I can't understand how in the world they can even interpret that date though.

Comment: @Anomie: Actually, it is very common in the computing industry (particularly mainframe-related) to refer to these things as "Julian dates".  This is not just colloquial either; it is baked into the official IBM special constants, system commands, and so forth.  The Wikipedia entry on Julian dates that you've linked to even mentions this usage of the term.

Comment: @JohnY: You mean in the sentence "The use of Julian date to refer to the day-of-year (ordinal date) is usually considered to be incorrect"?

Comment: @Anomie:  The rest of that sentence is "although it is widely used that way".  Look, when I first encountered it in the workplace, fresh out of school, I was appalled.  But ultimately Stack Overflow is *not* meant as an academic site; it's meant to *actually help people*.  In the real world of IT, especially in the world of IBM, which is explicitly the world being asked about in this question, *Julian date* means ordinal date.

Comment: I ended up creating a class that intreprets the dates after talking to someone who has worked with these dates for several years. I pretty much had to resort to if statements that evaluate the following rules. Any year value greater than or equal 49 is for the century 2000.
Any year value less than 49 is for the century 1900.
Century values are not returned from ASI. Leading zeros are not returned for years. 
 Leading zeros are not shown for days of year unless the year value is greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. I really thought I was not going to be able to figure this one out.

Comment: @dtinsley: "Leading zeros are not shown for days of year unless the year value is greater than 0." Does that mean that January 1, 2001 is actually encoded as "1001" after all?

Answer (score 2):

**IF** your dates are always of the format 'yyddd':

If you can write your SQL statement directly, the following will work...

```
SELECT CAST('20' || julianDate as date)
FROM table
```

If you don't, consider writing a view that incorporates that behaviour (that's one of the reasons views exist...).

For obvious reasons, all dates will be considered year 2000 and later...

**IF** (for whatever reason) it's removing any leading zeros in each part (as pointed out in comments for @Anomie's answer), you are indeed simply toast.  Frankly, the *entire* dataset is probably a loss, as I'm not sure how even RPG would be able to differentiate between certain dates properly at that point.

Comment: It works, but lately when I see a 2-digit year, there was a century field as well. But still doesn't help if 11 = 1/1/2001.

Comment: What is your actual date format string (or do you have a numeric datatype)?  It's possible that what you have is directly convertible to an actual date type.

Answer (score 2):

IBM defines *JUL date format as *yy/ddd*.  It is not commonly used, but is is an available standard format supported on the AS/400.  You say you have a string, so the assumption here is that it is stored as CHAR(5), or 5A in DDS.

If you column is called *jdt*, get the right number of digits in your string, in SQL, with:

```
  RIGHT(('00000' || TRIM(jdt)),5)
```

Now put the slash in:

```
  INSERT( RIGHT(('00000'||TRIM(jdt)),5) ,3,0,'/')
```

DB2/400 can cast this to a real date field, but it will only work properly if you can `SET OPTION DATFMT=*JUL`.  How to do this from C# on Windows would depend on how you are connecting.

Let's suppose you can't find the way to set the date format on your connection.

**Solution:** Create a user defined function [UDF] in DB2.

First, choose an appropriate library to store the function in, and set that as your current library.  In OS/400 CL, `CHGCURLIB yourlib`, or in SQL, `SET SCHEMA = yourlib`.  Thus by default anything you create will go into this library.

I recommend storing the SQL definition for your UDF in a source member. (Ask if unfamiliar)  You can execute the source with the `RUNSQLSTM` command.

Your function definition could look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  CvtJul2Date( jdtin char(5) ) RETURNS DATE            
        LANGUAGE SQL                                                  
        SPECIFIC CVTJUL2DT                                            
        DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION                              
        CONTAINS SQL                                                  
        RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT                                    
        SET OPTION DATFMT = *JUL                                      
  BEGIN                                                               
    RETURN(                                                           
          date( insert( right(('00000'||trim(jdtin)),5) ,3,0,'/') )   
    );                                                                
  END
```

The *JUL option is scoped to the UDF.  Any SQL query that runs on the AS/400 should be able to do this conversion, regardless of the DATFMT of the job (assuming you have put this function in a library which is on that job's library list).

Answer (score 1):

Oops... My bad. A method will still probably have to be written.

Based on your description, an increase of 1 is a new day? Looks like you will have to do some math to calculate the date. Maybe create a function like

```
public DateTime ConvertDate(int julianDate)
{

}
```

This is untested and may need some changes. But this would be my suggestion.

Comment: After looking at the data it looks like if there are 3 or less characters then the year is 2000 and the three characters are the ordinal days of the year. If there are more than 3 characters then the 4th and 5th characters are the years

Comment: Can you post some real date examples in the original question so we ca see them?